# test&set and test&test&set LOCK implementations in ASM for C

Tags: c, assembly, x86, mutex

Searching around for some test&set and test&test&set LOCK implementations on ASMx86 (x86 architecture) Assembly to use in my C codes. I don't want implementations in C, but plain assembly.

Please point me to some useful ones.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: test and set what exactly? Bits? Atomic values?

Comment: Oh and also it is "LOCK implementations" using test&set and test&test&set..

Comment: Would like to have 2 locks (one uses test&set and the other using test&test&set)... well maybe can use bit-test (bt) and bit-test-and-set (bts) ASM instructions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hare you have a simple implementation of test&set under IA32 x86

```
//eax = pointer on 32 bit lock variable
//Variable must be 4 byte aligned
//edx = bit test and set number from 0..31
lock    bts     dword ptr [eax], edx
        setnc   al         //al is 1 if bts instruction was successful
```

And hare you have a simple implementation of looped test&set

```
//eax = pointer on 32 bit lock variable
//Variable must be 4 byte aligned
//edx = bit test and set number from 0..31
@wait:
        pause                   //CPU hint for waiting in loop
lock    bts     dword ptr [eax], edx
        jc      @wait          //waiting in loop!!!
```

Remember waiting in loop will freeze the application thread so it is smart to also impement the maximum wait loop time.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the architecture, you can do this in a single instruction or by disabling interrupts.

80386 and later compatible architectures have the `bts` instruction which will do test-and-set atomically with the test result in the carry flag. [Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-atom/) is a great explanation of how to use PPC instructions to implement mutexes.

Others require something like:

```
cli         ;; Clear interrupts flag.
move r0, r1 ;; Copy the value into r0.
ori r1, 1   ;; Set the bit in r1 (r1 holds the value to test-and-set.)
sti         ;; Re-enable interrupts.
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and link. But didn't find a useful assembly code to use for both. Any other links that contain Assembly code for the two implementations of the lock?

Comment: I don't think this answer is very useful. `cli` and `sti` are not available unless you're writing your own operating system, and even then they will not help you achieve synchronization between multiple cpus/cores. You need to use the lock prefix rather than resurrecting the cause of the 80's and 90's constant system crashes...

Comment: @R: I've only ever had to implement these kinds of things while writing my own operating systems, and only on single core embedded chips. When using a modern processor, I use modern operating systems which have things like `HAL_TAS_SET`.